# Spiritual Causes For The Black Death?

Tags: history, death, reward-punishment

From Wiki “The Black Death was one of the most devastating pandemics in human history, resulting in the deaths of an estimated 75 to 200 million people in Eurasia and peaking in Europe in the years 1346–1353. The Black Death is estimated to have killed 30–60% of Europe's total population.” Obviously we can never know why HaShem does what he does, & mankind was behaving abhorrently as is best demonstrated that their response to this disease was ‘Kill the Jews’, but I was wondering if any prominent Rabbis ever explained what (specific) sins caused this Divine backlash. As usual any info would be great, thanks & be blessed!